# Keypair.generate() vs creating keypair with solana-keygen?

Tags: javascript, keypair, solana-keygen

I see two ways of generating Keypair. the easiest one is

```
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

const randomKey = Keypair.generate();
```

I see the other way which needs more work to do. first create a file

```
 solana-keygen grind --starts-with TAC:1
```

this will generate a JSON file: "TACsWaATBDYcvGjnZDQMcLjnbrjTAxoZeYmi3LofDRe.json"
Then we need to load from this

```
  import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
  import fs from "fs";

  const secret = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename).toString()) as number[];
  const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(secret);
  const kP=Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
```

they both return Keypair. I do not see any difference but I see some projects follow the second way. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `Keypair.generate()` generates a new *random* keypair everytime, while `Keypair.fromSecretKey()` allows you to *deterministically* load a keypair that you've generated earlier. In most usecases you save some type of state to your keypair, so generating a new one each time is not ideal.

If you're wondering why the second way does all the extra steps with loading from a file, this is for the reason that you're loading a private key, so the general principle of not having plaintext secrets inside your codebase applies.

Comment: in the second way, same file can be used to create only one token account. if you need to create multiple token accounts, you need to generate new file each time

Comment: Usually not. You'd use your one account saved in the file as your base, and derive all token accounts you need dynamically. You don't need a seperate private key for each of them. Check out [this](https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account#finding-the-associated-token-account-address) for more info.

Comment: Additionally looking at your question again, another benefit of doing it with the CLI like that is that you can specify a prefix with which your pubkey should start, in your example "TAC".

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, both of these methods to actually generate a keypair are the effectively the same. They randomly generate a brand new keypair.

The big difference is if you want to reuse the keypair you are generating.

### Generating via javascript

You can think of this method as "temporary keypairs by default" since you would have to write the extra code to save this keypair if you wanted to. So it makes it harder to reuse it.

This is often one of the most common ways to generate a new random "throw away" keypair. Like for testing or simple transactions.

Like you said, the code below will generate a brand new keypair. But it takes no really input. It is just random with no options.

```
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

const randomKey = Keypair.generate();
```

The big down side about using this method to generate a kyepair, is that if you airdrop tokens to this address, and do not take the time to save it, you are wasting tokens (even on devnet/testnet) and makes your code less efficient. Especially for tests.

### Generating via the Solana CLI

This method is "saved by default" since the CLI defaults to saving the generated keypair to the local filesystem (unless you use CLI flags to no save). But it does required the [Solana CLI](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools) to be installed

Generating keypairs with the CLI is more flexible since you can generate "vanity address" (like if you want the address to start with a certain string). But if you want to uses these addresses within your JavaScript/Typescript cod, you will have to manually import them and convert them into a format that the web3.js SDK understands (e.g. `Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey)`)

Generating via the CLI and loading into your JS code will both:

1. allow you to reuse the same address (so you always know the address your code will use), and
2. not throw away the tokens that are transferred to it (making it more efficient since you wont have to keep doing wasteful airdrops on devnet/tesnet)

The CLI will also let you "grind" for [vanity addresses](https://nick.af/articles/solana-vanity-addresses). Which can be a cool flex for addresses and programs :)

### Summary

Each method to generate and use is perfectly valid, each just has some tradeoffs.

Since most people only generate keypairs for tests, I personally recommend generating via the CLI and reusing that address as much as possible.